# XSD. Different between xsd:element and xs:element?

Tags: xsd, xjc

I reading articles about `XSD` on w3schools and here many examples. For example this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

But after I tried put this `.xsd` file in `xjc` - I see error log, dome like this:

```
The prefix "xs" for element "xs:schema" is not bound...
```

But all work correct when I change `xs` on `xsd` prefix.

So, can somebody, clarify for me what is different between `xs` and `xsd`?

Maybe, one prefix - it is old version and other for new version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**xs** and **xsd** are XML prefixes used with qualified names; each prefix must be associated with a namespace. The association is done with an attribute that looks like  *xmlns:xs="..."*. **xs** and **xsd** are most common for XML Schema documents.

Should you choose **s** or **ns1**, it shouldn't make any difference to any tool for your scenario.

The error is not caused by your XML Schema file. I suspect there might be something else in your setup, maybe a custom binding file. Please check that or post additional information.